# One ArrayList adding 2 different options

Tags: java, arraylist

My problem is that I have to use one Arraylist and adding two options

1.Task (contents,startTime,startEnd,difficulty)

> ```
> contents- String
> startTime,startEnd- Localtime
> difficulty- boolean easy/difficult
> ```

2. Happening (contents,startTime,startEnd,important,training)

> ```
> contents- String
> startTime,startEnd- Localtime
> important- boolean Yes/No
> training- boolean  Yes/No
> ```

Is it possible merge two different options to one arraylist ??

Comment: you can create a superclass and have these two classes extend it and have your list instantiated with the superclass

Comment: You can use `ArrayList<Object>`, but for what purpose?

Comment: Why do you need to store 2 separate concepts in the same list? Seems suspicious to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a common super class to those classes. For example an abstract class or an interface and then you will create the List upon that super-class or interface.

Answer (score 1):

Interface for common properties

```
public interface MyI {

    public String getContens();

    public LocalTime getStartTime();

    public LocalTime getStartEnd();

}
```

Then create models for reach of the unique instances:

```
public class Task implements MyI {

    private String contens;

    private LocalTime startTime;

    private LocalTime startEnd;

    private boolean difficulty;

    public boolean isDifficulty() {
        return difficulty;
    }

    public void setDifficulty(boolean difficulty) {
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }

    public void setContens(String contens) {
        this.contens = contens;
    }

    public void setStartTime(LocalTime startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public void setStartEnd(LocalTime startEnd) {
        this.startEnd = startEnd;
    }

    @Override
    public String getContens() {
        return this.contens;
    }

    @Override
    public LocalTime getStartTime() {
        return this.startTime;
    }

    @Override
    public LocalTime getStartEnd() {
        return this.startEnd;
    }

}

public class Happening implements MyI {

    private String contens;

    private LocalTime startTime;

    private LocalTime startEnd;

    private boolean important;

    private boolean training;

    public boolean isImportant() {
        return important;
    }

    public void setImportant(boolean important) {
        this.important = important;
    }

    public boolean isTraining() {
        return training;
    }

    public void setTraining(boolean training) {
        this.training = training;
    }

    public void setContens(String contens) {
        this.contens = contens;
    }

    public void setStartTime(LocalTime startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public void setStartEnd(LocalTime startEnd) {
        this.startEnd = startEnd;
    }

    @Override
    public String getContens() {
        return this.contens;
    }

    @Override
    public LocalTime getStartTime() {
        return this.startTime;
    }

    @Override
    public LocalTime getStartEnd() {
        return this.startEnd;
    }

}
```

Now you can create a list using the Interface to hold both types of models:

```
List<MyI> myList = new ArrayList<MyI>();
```